# mouseReleased never called after a JDialog is closed

Tags: java, swing

I have a button which is pressed and then released. While the button is pressed, an error can occur and a `JDialog` is shown. After closing the `JDialog`, the `mouseReleased(...)` method is never called. Is there a way to fix this?

#### How to reproduce the problem with the example:

1. Launch the program.
2. Press the button until the `JDialog` is shown (appears 5 seconds after you launch the program) .
3. `mouseReleased(...)` is never called after closing the `JDialog`.

   ```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
   import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

   public class testJDialog {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           JButton button = new JButton("Push me");

           button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                   System.out.println("pressed");
               }

               @Override
               public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                   System.out.println("released");
               }
           });

           // JDialog shown after 5 seconds.
           Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello");
               }
           });

           timer.setRepeats(false);
           timer.start();

           panel.add(button);
           frame.add(panel);
           frame.setLocation(0, 0);
           frame.setSize(800, 600);
           frame.setVisible(true);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why are you even adding a MouseListener and not an ActionListener to a JButton? This listener is not the appropriate one for this component.

Comment: Because I want to manage `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased`.

Comment: What is the underlying motivation that brought on this question in the first place, because I fear that it may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in disguise?

Comment: but there are other ways of doing this similar thing that are much more JButton friendly -- if we only knew what your underlying reasoning is.

Comment: It's used to move a slider. While the button is pressed, I move the slider. It's plus and minus buttons. What are these other ways you're talking of?

Comment: `I move the slider. It's plus and minus buttons` - why would you need buttons for this. You just click on the right/left side of the slider.

Comment: @camickr It's a custom made slider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a ChangeListener to the button's model for instance, something like so:

```
private class ModelListener implements ChangeListener {
    private boolean pressed = false;

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        boolean modelPressed = ((ButtonModel) e.getSource()).isPressed();
        if (modelPressed != pressed) {
            // if pressed state has changed
            pressed = modelPressed;  // update the state

            // and then do something with it
            System.out.println("Pressed: " + pressed);
        }
    }
}
```

Entire example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestingDialog2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 3000;
    private JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");

    public TestingDialog2() {
        button.getModel().addChangeListener(new ModelListener());

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        add(button);

        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, e -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestingDialog2.this, "Message");
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        }).start();
    }

    private class ModelListener implements ChangeListener {
        private boolean pressed = false;

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            boolean modelPressed = ((ButtonModel) e.getSource()).isPressed();
            if (modelPressed != pressed) {
                pressed = modelPressed;
                System.out.println("Pressed: " + pressed);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestingDialog2 mainPanel = new TestingDialog2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestingDialog2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

This should register accurately when the is no longer pressed, and not only that, should not work when the button has been disabled, something a MouseListener won't do correctly.

Comment: After the `JDialog` is closed, the `ChangeListener` is not called automatically though... You have to click the button again to trigger the "released".

Comment: @dguay: The released is called immediately when the dialog pops up, since the button loses focus and is no longer "Pressed". If you also want notification of the dialog closing, you'll have to listen for that. Again all depends on the overall needs.